# Mensagem de voto com menos de 15 reputação não traduzida

Tags: bug, tradução

A mensagem

> Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15
>   reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post
>   score

não está traduzida.

Esta mensagem aparece quando um utilizador com menos de 15 reputação tenta votar num *post*.

Sugiro a seguinte tradução:

> Obrigado pelo feedback! Os votos dos utilizadores com menos de
>   15 reputacao são guardados, mas não mudam a contagem de votos do post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Coloquei uma versão um pouco modificada no [nosso Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-pt) e vou deixar para alguém revisar.